# How can I move a div with sliding left/right/top/bottom? (jquery)

Tags: jquery, css, html, touch, sliding

How can I make a div move with sliding?
I made a game in jquery "bomb the zombies" and I want to move "bomberman" with sliding (left/right/top/bottom) and when I touch on the screen he has to place a bomb.

What is the code for touch and touch sliding?

[Link of my game](http://physicalmerchtem.netne.net)

Comment: Why did your site just take me to a known malware provider?

Comment: Jquery Mobile has some touch controls. Next time post the relevant code in a Fiddle or something.

Comment: @uʍopǝpısdn it is a free host website skip the adds or use an add blocker..

Comment: I think you should move to a reputable host

Comment: take a look at this here: https://jqueryui.com/draggable/

Comment: @uʍopǝpısdn   yes i know, but i only use the website for tests of jquery/html

Comment: @RobertStettler I need a slider in one direction(left/right/top/bottem)  and with a limit of 40px

Comment: Here, constrained: https://jqueryui.com/draggable/#constrain-movement

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways for example:

```
<div class='slide-box' style="position: relative;">
   <div class="inner-box" style="position: absolute;"></div>
</div>
```

(inner-box relative to slide-box)

and use offset() method OR css() method

http://api.jquery.com/css/
http://api.jquery.com/offset/